# how to get year and month from a whole date?

Tags: java, date

I've got:

```
String str = "2016-01-05" ;
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(str, formatter);
```

Now, the variable "date" contains the date "2016-01-05". 
How do I extract "2016-01" from that date and put it again into the variable "date" ?

Comment: What date do you want to generate? The 1st January 2016?

Comment: How is that a date?

Comment: Just ignore the day field?

Comment: yeah.. that was the question... how do I ignore it? The exercise is: 
get a whole date yyyy-MM-dd. Put it into a variable. Then, get only yyyy-MM from that, and then put this new date into the same variable (overwrite)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are only interested in the year and the month, the best class would be [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html). A `LocalDate` *requires* a day.

You can create an instance with:

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from(date);
```

Comment: ym will be of type YearMonth, not LocalDate, no? 
can I do date = ym ?

Comment: @Marco yes it will and no you can't. A LocalDate has a day, you can't remove it, that's the way the class was designed. You should maybe give a bit more context if a YearMonth is not useful for your problem.